# Consulta cuyo resultado incluya un campo que sea resultado de otra consulta en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla de personas que tiene entre otros campos los siguientes:

```
+----------------------------+
|persona_id | persona_nombre |
+-----------+----------------+
| 1         | persona 1      |
| 2         | persona 2      |
+-----------+----------------+
```

Y tengo una tabla de padrones con los siguientes campos:

```
+--------------------------+
|persona_nombre | padrones |
+---------------+----------+
| persona 1     | 1,2      |
| persona 2     | 1        |
+--------------------------+
```

Hay alguna manera de hacer una consulta que devuelva lo siguiente:

```
+-----------------------+
|persona_id | padron_id |
+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | 1         |
| 1         | 2         |
| 2         | 1         |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Lo que buscas parece ser una [tabla dinámica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabla_dinámica) (conocida mejor en inglés como *pivot table*). MySQL no ofrece una manera nativa para hacerlo. Lo más recomendable es procesar esto a nivel de aplicación para que luzca como quisieras.

Comment: La columna padrones es un varchar y el contenido esta separado por comas?

Comment: @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez La columna padrones seria parte del resultado y contendría el listado de los padrones a los que pertence la persona, la coma la puse como ejemplo pero podrían estar entre paréntesis o separados por guiones, por ejemplo (1)(2) o 1 - 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
 SELECT A.persona_nombre, (
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(B.padron_id SEPARATOR ',')
   FROM padrones AS B
   WHERE B.persona_id = A.persona_id
   GROUP BY B.persona_id
 ) AS padrones
 FROM personas AS A
```

O así también:

```
 SELECT A.persona_nombre, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(B.padron_id SEPARATOR ',') AS padrones
 FROM personas AS A
 INNER JOIN padrones AS B 
   ON B.persona_id = A.persona_id
 GROUP BY A.persona_id
```

Comment: @Pillo, Vale la pena mencionar que en la segunda opción, si una persona no pertenece a un padrón no aparecerá. Si quisieras que si aparezca, simplemente deberías usar `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @MarcosGallardo ambas funcionaron a la perfección